# On the relationship between second and first part of fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

The [italian Wikipedia article about the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_fondamentale_del_calcolo_integrale) states it as such (I have summarized a bit):

First part:
Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function continuous in the $(a,b)$ interval. Then its antiderivative $F$ exists in the interval and $F(x)=\int_a^x{f(t)dt}$. Moreover (corollary) if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and admits antiderivative $G$, then $\int_a^b{f(t)dt}=G(b) - G(a)$.

Second part:
Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function that admits an antiderivative $F$, then $\int_a^b{f(t)dt}=F(b) - F(a)$.

What confuses me a bit is the [statement in the article](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_fondamentale_del_calcolo_integrale#Relazione_fra_i_due_teoremi) that if $f$ is continuous then the first part can be derived from the second "using the basic properties of the derivative".

Can someone confirm this and show me how this works?

The existence of an antiderivative is needed as a hypothesis in the second part so how do we apply the second theorem? In the particular case in which $f$ is continuous I would rather derive the second from the first (if $f$ is continuous then it is also Riemann integrable).

I understand that the assumptions of the two parts are different, because in the first part we assume continuity and we do not assume the existence of an antiderivative, which is the thesis, while in the second part we do not assume continuity and we do assume the existence of the antiderivative, that in the thesis is used to calculate the definite integral.

Apologies to non italian readers, you will have to trust my translation:)

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then it is also Riemann integrable. So the second part applies and can be used to derive the first. You specifically can't go the other way around, because you can't use the first part of the assumptions are the weaker ones used in the first part. As a rule of thumb (with a lot of exceptions, though!), theorems with stronger assumptions can be derived from those with weaker assumptions.

Comment: thanks!!. but I am not sure though. i did not want to derive the second in general, but to assume $f$ continous and see if we can apply 2+continuity of f to derive 1 or, viceversa 1+continuity of to derive 2. it is true that continuity is stronger than   riemann integrability, but  I understand 2 also requires the existence of an antiderivative as part of the hypothesis while 1 does not. however, if f is continuous the requirement of the antiderivative is automaticallly satisfied thanks to 1 and the the thesis of 2 is just the corollary of 1. but i am not sure about the other way around!

Comment: @I4teLearner This is a pretty good question. Integrating any function with a jump discontinuity (assuming it is Riemann Integrable) does not admit an antiderivative since derivatives do not admit jump discontinuities

Comment: thanks! actually my question was related to the continuous case. I read that for continuous functions the theorem just collapses to a single statement so I wondered what did it meant to derive the first part from the second in that case